# get Value of Selected drop down Item using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

By default I have set value of drop down to 1.But when I want to retrieve that value in click event I get error. Value of that item I get it as "undefined"

```
$("#cmbTicketType option[value='1']").prop("selected", true);
```

I tried this

```
var sTicketType = $('#cmbTicketType').val();
alert(sTicketType );
```

HTML:

```
    <select id="cmbTicketType" name="cmbTicketType" multiple="multiple" style="display: none; ">                             
<option value="1">FLM</option>
<option value="7">Bank</option>
<option value="5">Electrical</option>
<option value="3">Network</option>
<option value="6">Power Failure</option>
<option value="2">SLM</option>
<option value="8">Suspect</option>
<option value="4">UPS</option>
                            </select>
```

Comment: If you post your full code, it will be helpful to solving the problem.

Comment: @bla - not the **full code**.  Only the relevant parts - we don't want to encourage "wall of code" posts :)

Comment: Solved I Just removed multiple from HTML :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **set** the "selected" value of a `<select>` element the same way you **extract** it's selected value.

To set the value -

```
$("#cmbTicketType").val(1);
```

Then you can retrieve the value the same way you are doing now -

```
var sTicketType = $("#cmbTicketType").val();
```

---

### [Here is a simple jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GHyCL/2/)

Comment: Now it gives value as "null" :(

Comment: @sag - Checkout my jsFiddle example, the code works, perhaps there is some other problem with the surrounding code?  Where exactly are you extracting the value of the dropdown?  Does the element exist when you make the call?

Comment: I am very Confused..Whats wrong with my case then ? it shows either null or undefined...but the selected text " FLM " appears properly when form load happens

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?  I am also slightly confused because this code (as shown in the jsFiddle demo) is working...

Answer (score -1):

Question little unclear. Assuming `#cmbTicketType` is the id of select tag, you ccan get value by

```
var sTicketType = $('#cmbTicketType option:selected').val();
```

Comment: It gives me values as "undefined" :(

Comment: Note that this is a multi selection select element.  Your code will only return the value of the first selected option and not all of them. [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/GHyCL/3/)

Comment: @SagarDumbre: It gives undefined as no option selected here from code and probably also from browser.